# Using typedef enum as a new type

Tags: typedef

I got a beginner question and I've surfed through the Internet and only find definition like

```
typedef enum
{
    A,B,C,D
}CAP;
CAP a=A; // printf("%d",a); => 1
```

But my question is (from Stanford CS107 section handout ) that :

```
typedef enum { 
 Integer, String, List, Nil 
} nodeType; 
// skip
char *ConcatAll(nodeType *list) 
{ 
 switch (*list) { 
 case Integer: 
 case Nil: return strdup(""); 
 case String: return strdup((char *)(list + 1)); 
 } 
 nodeType **lists = (nodeType **)(list + 1); 
 // skip after
}
```

Since the nodeType is numeric (1 , 2, 3), how come it could be used as type declaration

```
nodeType *list;
```

and even this?

```
nodeType **lists = (nodeType **)(list + 1);
```

Or maybe there's a manual so I can find? Thank you for your kind advice!

Comment: A type defined with `typedef` can be used wherever type names are allowed, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a type with `typedef`, you can use it wherever a type can be used. It's treated as if you'd used the type that was defined. So:

```
nodeType *list;
```

is equivalent to:

```
enum {Integer, String, List, Nil} *list;
```